# Write txt to Oculus Quest 2 and read it out on PC

Tags: unity-game-engine, permissions, txt, oculusquest

I have developed a Unity game that will be used for research purposes. The time that the player needs per level is written in a txt file. On PC it works fine. But I can't find it anywhere when I read the Oculus files with sidequest or android file transfer on my PC. I changed the permission in Unity under `Project Settings -> Write Permission` to `External(SD)` and added the lines in the Android Manifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I have also tried all possible paths (`Application.dataPath`, `Application.persistentDataPath` and `/sdcard/filename`, `/mnt/sdcard/filename`,...)
I have also restarted the Oculus several times.

This is the code I'm creating and saving the txt:

```
if (SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name == "Level1")
        {
            //Path of the file
            string path = Application.dataPath + "/SteamingAssets/CoordinateTimeLog" + ".txt";
            //Create file if it doesn't exist
            if(!File.Exists(path)){
                File.WriteAllText(path, "Path the Player walked (x,y,z) + Time in seconds\n\n");
            }
            //Content of the file
            string content = "Level 1: " + transform.position +"   "+ System.DateTime.Now + "\n\n";
            //Add coordinates to it
            File.AppendAllText(path, content);
        }
```

In the AndroidManifest.xml I've added the following under `</application>`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Could you show your code? As alternative I'd recommend to directly send the data to the PC e.g. via TCP or (what I did for my thesis) host an HTTP server on the PC and directly wrote the file to the PC via web request

Comment: I've added the code in the question. Thanks for the alternatives. I'll check them

Comment: Streaming assets is **read-only** after a build! Rather use the [persistentDataPath](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-persistentDataPath.html)!

Comment: Also do you get any error or only `I can't find it anywhere`?

Comment: I've also already tried the persistentDataPath. And no, I don't get any error. There is just nothing in visible in any folder when I search the folders via sidequest or android  file transfer

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this issue?